# How to revert color settings for a Button font text in XCode8 Editor

Tags: ios, uibutton, xcode8

Does anyone know how to get back de "default" font color of a Button text?

[image: Original state]

[image: State that I want to discard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Xcode version 8.1]

Just toggle between Attributed and Plain it will be set to default, Let me know if worked ? Also which XCode version you are using

Comment: Thank you. I thought there was a more intuitive solution.